# Left over SSH processes / jobs?

Tags: php, bash, ssh

I'm using the PHP library `phpseclib0.2.2` to automate SSHing into one of my servers. I have it set up to a cron task that runs every 5 minutes.

Upon logging out after setting it up, making sure it runs, etc, I saw the following:

```
$ logout
There are stopped jobs.
$
```

And I was forced to use

```
$ logout
```

again to logout. Are there a bunch of SSH processes / jobs that are running on my server that I never close How can I "check this" in terminal with bash command (or some better way)?

Below is the code I use.

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.com');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('some command');
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You've probably started some processes and either sent them to background, e. g. with a trailing ampersand like `sleep 60 &` or by pressing `^Z`.

You can use the `jobs` command to list running or suspended jobs in your current shell. If you want to keep them running after you close the shell you first need to `disown` them and then send them into background with `bg`.

```
$ sleep 1000 &
[1] 2345
$ sleep 2000
^Z
[2]+  Stopped                 sleep 2000
$ jobs
[1]-  Running                 sleep 1000 &
[2]+  Stopped                 sleep 2000
$ kill %2
$ kill %1
[1]-  Terminated              sleep 1000
[2]+  Terminated              sleep 2000
```

If you want to keep processes running after you've quit the shell and already know that in advance you should use `nohup` to start these processes or write a proper init script.

Comment: And you can ask for them with `jobs`.

Comment: ok thanks. when I ssh in and use `jobs` it doesn't return anything. I assume this means no left over jobs running?

Comment: Yes, if `jobs` doesn't output anything there are no jobs attached to the current shell.

@glglgl: Uhm, yes. I think that's what I wrote…